# Problema ao imprimir o conteúdo de um vetor

Tags: java, array

Como fazer um acumulador de pontuação para cada  resposta.

```
package modulo02;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class vetorGabarito {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pontuacao = 0, n, i, j = 0;
        float s = 0, maiorMedia = -1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Quantos alunos há na turma?: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        String nome[] = new String[n];
        char resposta[][] = new char[n][3];
        float media[] = new float[n];
        char gabarito[] = new char[3];

        for (int g = 0; g < gabarito.length; g++) {
            System.out.println("Gabarito questão[" + g + "]: ");
            gabarito[g] = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nome do aluno: ");
            nome[i] = sc.next();



            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.println("Resposta nº " + (j + 1));
                resposta[i][j] = sc.next().charAt(0);


                if (resposta[i][j] == gabarito[j]) {

                    pontuacao++;
                }


            }

            System.out.println("Pontuação: " + pontuacao);


        }

        System.out.println("Relatório geral: ");
        System.out.println("resposta - aluno");


        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(nome[i]);



        }

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.println(resposta[j]);




            }




    }
}
```

[image: sdsa]

Queria que os nomes ficassem embaixo de Alunos e as respostas embaixo de Respostas.

Comment: Qual a relação da pergunta com swing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Tanto `char[] x = new char[n]`, quanto `char x[] = new char[n]` são compilados normalmente, como o @Diego Felipe disse. No entanto, é preferível que a segunda forma seja evitada, de acordo com a documentação oficial (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

**Dúvida 1:**

Você já tem uma variável `q` que representa todos os conjuntos de respostas dentro daquele loop `for`, então você poderia aproveitar isso para fazer uma matriz, ou seja, um vetor de vetores, para o seu `respostaVetor`, que ficaria assim:

```
char[][] respostaVetor = new char[n][10];
```

Dessa forma, na hora de guardar as respostas, você só precisaria fazer:

```
respostaVetor[q][i] = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

E depois, para ler, um loop semelhante, que acessa o grupo de respostas de um aluno e depois a resposta propriamente dita:

```
System.out.println("\nResposta nº" + q + " \nQuestão[" + i + "]: " + respostaVetor[q][i]);
```

**Dúvida 2:**

Para guardar a pontuação de cada aluno individualmente, você só precisaria de mais um vetor de `int`s, algo como

```
int[] pontuacao = new int[n];
```

Comment: Tanto faz entre as duas formas que você salientou. Pro java, isso é indiferente, se você faz `tipo variavel[]` ou `tipo[] variavel`, ele reconhece como vetor da mesma forma. Não há problema em fazer em nenhuma das duas formas.

Comment: @MrPingu Fiz uma matriz como você falou, agora me apareceu outro problema, quando eu vou exibir os nomes e as respostas, para você entender melhor eu coloquei uma foto do meu stack trace no post.

Comment: @MrPingu A primeira dúvida eu já consegui resolver com sua ajuda, agora a parte da pontuação e como eu vou mostrar isso é que ainda tenho problema.E também o jeito de mostrar os nomes e as respostas ainda não sei como resolver, será que é porque eu estou utilizando 2 for? Um para nomes e um para respostas, eu não deveria usar só um for? para mostrar tudo?Já tentei de tudo, mas ainda não consegui.

Comment: A ideia de usar dois loops `for` está correta, você só tem que colocar o das respostas dentro do loop que passa pelos nomes, ao invés de separados, e então exibe como `System.out.print(nome[i] + " - " resposta[j])`. 

No caso da pontuação, tente fazer como eu descrevi, um outro vetor com o mesmo número de elementos que o de alunos (`n`, no caso) e adicione a pontuação em `if (resposta[i][j] == gabarito[j])` com `pontuacao[i]++`, sendo `i` a posição daquele aluno no vetor.